# Range.Find method giving inconsistent results

Tags: excel, vba, find

I've developed a routine that loops through workbooks/worksheets, finds a maximum value in a column, writes a corresponding cell's value to the main workbook, and repeats. Within this routine is a line of code that uses the Range.Find method to set the location of the maximum value in the column. I have been encountering issues with several of the sheets returning errors, which for the time being are being handled by simply writing "Error" to the cell "BreakVoltCell" in the main workbook. The errors occur seemingly at random, sometimes working for one sheet in a workbook and failing for the next, however it's the same sheets on each run so I believe there's a reason. The code is as follows:

```
'Get breakdown voltage
Dim rngSlope As Range
Set rngSlope = CurrentFile.Sheets(SheetName).Range("E2:E" & _ 
Sheets(SheetName).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)

Dim BreakVoltSlope As Double
BreakVoltSlope = WorksheetFunction.Max(rngSlope)

Dim BreakVoltLoc As Range
Set BreakVoltLoc = rngSlope.Find(BreakVoltSlope, Sheets(SheetName).Range("E2"), _ 
xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext, False, False, False)

Dim BreakVolt As Double
BreakVolt = BreakVoltLoc.Offset(0, -3).Value
BreakVoltCell.Value = BreakVolt
Set BreakVoltCell = BreakVoltCell.Offset(1, 0)
```

Through basic debugging and using some line number specifications and error line outputs I've confirmed that it is the find method that is failing to return a range. I've read on several forums that specifying all parameters for the method can alleviate this as many parameters can get changed during runtime and will be reused in their changed state on the next loop. However after trying this the error persists, while changing these parameters I also thought it was strange that using xlFormulas for the LookIn parameter worked while xlValues did not (returned errors for all sheets instead of only some). To debug further I put a breakpoint in the error handler and used the immediate window to test the logical equivalency between the variable holding the max value "BreakVoltSlope" and the cell in the test range where I knew the maximum value was. The test between BreakVoltSlope and the cell's formula returned FALSE while the test between BreakVoltSlope and the cell's value returned TRUE, this immediately raised questions since as I mentioned earlier using xlValues in the LookIn parameter failed. What is even more confounding is that afterwards I did the same tests after a sheet that worked properly and found that once again formula comparison returned FALSE and value comparison returned TRUE!

I feel I must be fundamentally misunderstanding how the Find method works, the logical comparisons not only suggest that my code shouldn't work when using xlFormulas as the search region, but they also suggest that it should work when using xlValues which it doesn't. Instead it works for >90% of sheets when using xlFormulas but not all of them. If anyone has a deep understanding of where this inconsistency comes from I'm curious to hear! If I can provide any more detail let me know.

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking. Your code sample doesn't seem to relate to the comparisons you mention. Is the issue to do with the Lookin parameter? Think we need an [mcve].

Comment: Would not hurt to be more consistent with your use of `CurrentFile` to qualify `Sheets(SheetName)`  If you have multiple workbooks open that could potentially cause problems.  `LookIn` should definitely be xlValues - changing that to `xlFormulas` to get it to "work" is leading you away from the root cause of the problem.